# Using node-sass to add min.css file extension in the end of compressed file

Tags: css, sass, package.json, node-sass

I can't seem to figure out how to change compiled and compressed file extension with node-sass.
right now I tried different variations but it still compiles scss to style.css file.

I tried this

```
node-sass --watch scss -o dist --output-style compressed --out-file-extension .min.css
```

I also tried this

```
node-sass --watch scss -o dist/style.min.css --output-style compressed
```

Comment: Note that [LibSass and Node Sass are deprecated](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-sass)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't figure out how to do it with node-sass so I used Sass instead.

I accomplished the result I wanted with installing

```
npm install sass --save-dev
```

And adding this to my package.json

```
sass --watch scss/style.scss:dist/style.min.css --style compressed
```

scss/style.scss being the folder and file I want to compress and dist/style.min.css is the destination

Add this if you don't want the .map file

```
--no-source-map
```

Comment: Do you know how you'd do this if saving to multiple files? rather than compiling it into one file? I mean with .min suffix added.

Comment: No I'm not familiar with that

Comment: I figured out how to do it. Had to use gulp in the end. Thanks for replying.